# kill a running child process in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to kill/access a process. It should start a other bot and also be able to kill it. Here is what I've done.

```
const { Client,  Intents, DiscordAPIError } = require("discord.js");
const client = new Client({
  intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS]
});
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require (`discord.js`)
const child = require (`child_process`)

module.exports = {
    name: `start`,
    description: `start the bot`,
    execute(message, args){
        child.exec(`node test.js`, (stderr, stdout) => {
          message.channel.send(`stderr: ${stderr}, stdout: ${stdout}`)
        })

        
}
}
```

This is the command where I want to stop the bot.

```
const { Client,  Intents, DiscordAPIError } = require("discord.js");
const client = new Client({
  intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS]
});
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require (`discord.js`)
const child = require (`child_process`)

module.exports = {
    name: `stop`,
    description: `stop the bot`,
    execute(message, args){
      //no idea what to put here
        })

    




}
}
```

Can I get the process id or save something in a variable to access the process?
Thanks for helping ;)

Answer (score 0):

This will terminate your program

```js
process.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

add `process.exit()`

like this

```js
const {
    Client,
    Intents,
    DiscordAPIError
} = require("discord.js");
const client = new Client({
    intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS]
});
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require(`discord.js`)
const child = require(`child_process`)

module.exports = {
    name: `stop`,
    description: `stop the bot`,
    execute(message, args) {
        process.exit()
    })

}
}
```